# Last cell Not Showing Properly in Tableview

Tags: ios

I use `Tableview` to show library songs and songs play on did select cell,
when song play mini player popup on bottom.

At that time last cell of table view is not show properly, some of its portion hide behind mini player so please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Zip your code and send the link i have to check it where is the problem

Comment: i think it is the problem of tableview frame.

Comment: can you share screenshot of tableview in storyboard ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set `contentInset`

```
 tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 110, 0); values are - top, left, bottom, right // change as per your needs
```

OR

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CGFloat navbarHeight = 44; // this is supposed to be 64 but you should dynamically calculate it or better use constraints
    CGRect tempFrame = self.view.frame;
    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tempFrame.origin.x, tempFrame.origin.y, tempFrame.size.width, tempFrame.size.height - navbarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix can be to add a footer View to your tableview. make the footer view height the same as your mini player. customise the footer view to your needs or make the footer view background colour to clear so it will not be visible.